# Convert a BST to sorted doubly linked list(Debug)

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, binary-tree

Here is a function to convert a binary search tree to sorted doubly linked list.The idea is to do an inorder traversal and put the visited node in a circular array of size 2.The left and right pointers are then adjusted for conversion to doubly linked list.Right pointer of current node is never modified and accessed later.Where is the problem?

```
void TreetoQueue(node* tnode)
 {static node* arr[2]={NULL,NULL};
  static int index=0;
    if(tnode==NULL) return;
    TreetoQueue(tnode->left);
    arr[index]=tnode;        //current node
    if(arr[1]!=NULL)
      {  if(index==0) 
         {arr[1]->right=arr[0]; //modify right pointer of inorder predecessor to point to current node
         arr[0]->left=arr[1];  //modify current node's left pointer to point to inorder predecessor 
         }

       if(index==1)
       {arr[0]->right=arr[1];
       arr[1]->left=arr[0];
       }
     cout<<"index-"<<index<<"  "<<arr[0]->val<<"  "<<arr[1]->val<<"\n";
     }

  index=(index+1)%2;
  TreetoQueue(tnode->right);
  }

          _______5______
         /              \
      ___3__             6__
     /      \               \
    1       4               _9
                           /  \
                           7  10


 index-1  1  3
 index-0  4  3
 index-1  4  5
 index-0  6  5
 index-1  6  7
 index-0  9  7  
 index-1  9  10
 node->left->left->right is NULL //Intended to be 3
 node->left->right->left is NULL//intended to be 3 
 node->left->right->right is NULL//intended to be 5
```

Edit: It works as intended.Only that i had to change the root to start of the list.I used another function to do this.Could i have achieved this without an extra function?

```
    node* TreetoQueue2(node* root)
      {node* head=root;
       while(head->left!=NULL)
        head=head->left;
       TreetoQueue(root);
       return head;
       }
```

Comment: You say `if(arr[1] != NULL)`. Initially its declared as `NULL`. I don't see it change anytime after. Is there is something I am missing?

Comment: arr[index]=tnode and index=(index+1)%2.arr[1] changes as you can see it in the output

Comment: Can you explain your bizarre indentation scheme?

Comment: I think it is because index is static, but I can't understand your idea

Comment: Are you sure your tree is what you believe it is? I don't see any cause for a segfault in the posted code, if it receives a valid tree.

Comment: I don't know where the problem causing the segfault is, but it's probably not in the code you posted. That works here without a problem. Following the code path, it is correct as far as I can see, as long as you only call it on one valid tree. If you try to convert more than one tree with it, the second conversion finds the state left over from the first, and that can cause havoc (and will cause undesired behaviour - don't use statics, pass parameters). If you call it on a 'tree' that isn't, e.g. if `7->right == 7`, you can easily get the observed result.

Comment: Yes it doesn't seg-fault.I used (node* &tnode) by mistake.But still it doesn't behave as expected node->left->left->right is NULL whereas it should have been 3

Answer (score 0):

To reiterate what Daniel said, the following test code works (with g++-4.7) as expected:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node {
        node * left;
        node * right;
        int val;
};

typedef node * node_ptr;

void TreetoQueue(node* tnode) {

        static node* arr[2]={NULL,NULL};

        static int index=0;

        if(tnode==NULL) return;

        TreetoQueue(tnode->left);

        arr[index]=tnode;        //current node

        if(arr[1]!=NULL)
        {  
                if(index==0) 
                {
                        arr[1]->right=arr[0]; //modify right pointer of inorder predecessor to point to current node
                        arr[0]->left=arr[1];  //modify current node's left pointer to point to inorder predecessor 
                }

                if(index==1)
                {
                        arr[0]->right=arr[1];
                        arr[1]->left=arr[0];
                }
                cout<<"index-"<<index<<"  "<<arr[0]->val<<"  "<<arr[1]->val<<"\n";
        }

        index=(index+1)%2;
        TreetoQueue(tnode->right);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        node_ptr np0 = new node();
        node_ptr np1 = new node();
        node_ptr np2 = new node();
        node_ptr np3 = new node();
        node_ptr np4 = new node();
        node_ptr np5 = new node();
        node_ptr np6 = new node();
        node_ptr np7 = new node();

        np0->val = 5;
        np1->val = 3;
        np2->val = 1;
        np3->val = 4;
        np4->val = 6;
        np5->val = 9;
        np6->val = 7;
        np7->val = 10;

        np0->left = np1;
        np1->left = np2;
        np1->right = np3;

        np0->right = np4;
        np4->right = np5;

        np5->left = np6;
        np5->right = np7;


        TreetoQueue(np0);


}
```

Comment: I expected the code to re-arrange the left and right pointers to point to inorder predecessor and successor respectively(forming a doubly linked list) but somehow they remain unchanged

Comment: @rAkesH Works here, the pointers are transformed as they should. After converting the tree to a doubly linked list with `TreetoQueue`, I can traverse the list left to right and right to left, giving the expected results. The problem is in the code you're not showing us.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes it works indeed! My bad.Now i had to change the root to start of the list i used a helper function to return the leftmost tree node and call TreetoQueue.

Answer (score 0):

I've written what I think is a simpler, more elegant solution that still plays on the idea of a recursive inorder traversal, but doesn't require allocating any memory in each call:

```
Node* Inorder(Node* _n, Node*& _listHead, Node* _lastP=NULL){
  if (_n->left)
    _lastP = Inorder(_n->left, _listHead, _lastP);
  if (_lastP){
    _lastP->right = _n;
    _n->left = _lastP;
  }else
    _listHead = _n;
  if (_n->right)
    return Inorder(_n->right, _listHead, _n);
  return _n;
}
```

The idea is to track the last element that was appended to the list (`_lastP`). As it's written, the code will destroy the binary search tree structure in place of a sorted doubly-linked list.

Here's the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Node{
  int data;
  Node* left;
  Node* right;
  Node(int _d=0):data(_d),left(NULL),right(NULL){}
};

Node* Inorder(Node* _n, Node*& _listHead, Node* _lastP=NULL){
  if (_n->left)
    _lastP = Inorder(_n->left, _listHead, _lastP);
  if (_lastP){
    _lastP->right = _n;
    _n->left = _lastP;
  }else
    _listHead = _n;
  if (_n->right)
    return Inorder(_n->right, _listHead, _n);
  return _n;
}

Node* BSTtoSortedDoublyLinkedList(Node* _treeRoot){
  if(!_treeRoot)
    return NULL;
  Node* listHead = NULL;
  Node* listTail = Inorder(_treeRoot, listHead);
  //could make circular with following lines
  //listHead->left = listTail; listTail->right = listHead;
  return listHead;
}

int main(){
  //create our tree
  Node* root = new Node(5);
  Node* n1 = new Node(3);
  Node* n2 = new Node(1);
  Node* n3 = new Node(4);
  Node* n4 = new Node(6);
  Node* n5 = new Node(9);
  Node* n6 = new Node(7);
  Node* n7 = new Node(10);

  root->left = n1;
  n1->left = n2;
  n1->right = n3;
  root->right = n4;
  n4->right = n5;
  n5->left= n6;
  n5->right = n7;
  /*

         _______5______
        /              \
     ___3__             6__
    /      \               \
   1       4               _9
                          /  \
                          7  10
  */

  Node* linkedList = BSTtoSortedDoublyLinkedList(root);
  while(linkedList){
    cout << linkedList->data << " ";
    linkedList = linkedList->right;
  }
  return 0;
}
```